# Updated Tk, broke .destroy

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I've been working with tkinter (from python 3.2 and 3.4) for the past year or so and have never had issues with widgets destroying.

I recently updated my version of Tk/Tcl (to ActiveTcl 8.5.18) and also updated my operating system (to MacOS 10.11). At first it seemed no windows would destroy, but I've since discovered that if a process remains running, then destroy will simply freeze the window.

The code below displays this issue:

```
#! usr/local/bin/python3.4

class kill_test:
    def __init__(self,r=None):
        import tkinter as tk
        if r is None:
            r=tk.Tk()
        self.r=r
        self.forever_flag=False
        self.withdraw=False
        self.buttons=[
            tk.Label(r,text='Set Hold Flag',relief='groove'),
            tk.Label(r,text='Destroy Root',relief='groove'),
            tk.Label(r,text='Withdraw and Destroy',relief='groove'),
            tk.Label(r,text='Destroy Self',relief='groove'),
            tk.Label(r,text='Quit Root',relief='groove'),
            tk.Label(r,text='Withdraw and Quit',relief='groove'),
            tk.Label(r,text='Make Toplevel',relief='groove')
            ]
        def r_destroy(s=self):
            print('root.destroy called')
            s.r.destroy()
        def b_destroy(s=self):
            print('button.destroy called')
            for b in self.buttons:
                if 'Self' in b['text']:
                    b.destroy()
        def r_quit(s=self):
            print('root.quit called')
            self.r.quit()
        def f_flag(s=self):
            print('changing loop_flag')
            self.forever_flag=(not self.forever_flag)
            for b in self.buttons:
                if 'Flag' in b['text']:
                    if self.forever_flag:
                        b.base_fg='red'
                    else:
                        b.base_fg='black'
        def w_destroy(s=self):
            print('withdrawing and destroying')
            self.r.withdraw()
            self.r.destroy()
        def w_quit(s=self):
            print('withdrawing and quitting')
            self.r.withdraw()
            self.r.quit()
        def t_cmd(s=self):
            T=tk.Toplevel()
            kill_test(T)
        self.cmds=[
            f_flag,
            r_destroy,
            w_destroy,
            b_destroy,
            r_quit,
            w_quit,
            t_cmd
            ]
        i=0;j=0
        for b,cmd in zip(self.buttons[:-1],self.cmds[:-1]):
            b.base_fg=b['fg']
            b.bind('<Enter>',lambda e:e.widget.config(bg='lightblue',fg='white'))
            b.bind('<Button-1>',lambda e:e.widget.config(bg='darkblue'))
            b.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',lambda e,c=cmd:(e.widget.config(bg='lightblue'),c()))
            b.bind('<Leave>',lambda e:e.widget.config(bg='white',fg=e.widget.base_fg))
            b.grid(row=i,column=j,sticky='ew')
            i+=1
            if i>2:
                i=0
                j+=1
        b=self.buttons[-1];cmd=self.cmds[-1]
        b.base_fg=b['fg']
        b.bind('<Enter>',lambda e:e.widget.config(bg='lightblue',fg='white'))
        b.bind('<Button-1>',lambda e:e.widget.config(bg='darkblue'))
        b.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',lambda e,c=cmd:(e.widget.config(bg='lightblue'),c()))
        b.bind('<Leave>',lambda e:e.widget.config(bg='white',fg=e.widget.base_fg))
        b.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky='ew')

    def run(self):
        self.r.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    import time
    t=kill_test()
    t.run()
    if t.forever_flag:
        time.sleep(10)
```

Calling from the command line, if one does not press the "Set Hold Flag' button, then everything exits smoothly.

On the other hand, if one does press it, then trying to destroy the window via any mechanism just freezes the window in place until time.sleep exits.

It used to be that the window would at least disappear first.

If one calls the 'Withdraw and destroy' button, the window remains visible but inactive. If one calls the 'Withdraw and quit' button, though, it disappears.

Lastly, toplevel windows will destroy fine (as expected, considering that the loop was never called), regardless of what is done to them. I put in a toplevel button version of the test.

Does anyone have hints as to how I can get the old behaviour back?

Comment: Are you asking how to get `destroy` to destroy and hide the windows after `mainloop` exits but before `time.sleep(10)` finishes?

Comment: Playing around with the above some more, yes. The mac-packaged version of the Tk framework must have done just that. I figured out that as a work-around I can just check whether the window I'm calling destroy on is the root window or not and route to withdraw and quit in that case, but if you know how to get destroy to hide the windows, that would be preferable.

Comment: There have been a number of changes inside the guts of Tk. The way you're seeing now is how it is _supposed_ to work. You need an asynchronous wait in the GUI thread…